# Is this edit working?

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions

Ok, let's settle something here.

I would like the people who closed my question to come to state their case.

I would like the people who have closed my question on wattage to copy and paste the say what is wrong with my question.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not clearly written.

In general, there are two kinds of questions: **concrete** questions about a specific case, and **theoretical** questions. "What [power level] is safe" suggests a concrete question. In that case, you should specify which band(s) you are building a radio for ('kHz and MHz' is impossibly wide) and what type of safety you are considering (safety of the user? safety of components? compliance with interference regulations?).

It would also help to give more *context* on your question. Add this information to your question: Why are you proposing to use brass strips? **This sounds like an odd choice for radio construction, so you should explain what you want to achieve by doing it,** or instead ask a question about circuit construction rather than safe power levels.

Also, your sentences have unclear phrasing. This causes people to have a poor impression of your request for help, but it also makes the question ambiguous, which is bad. For example, you wrote "is it safe to have these Brass strips do this until I have signals being emitted by this network inside of my radio". By "…do this until…" do you mean that "signals being emitted inside the radio" is what you are trying to *achieve* or what you are trying to *avoid*?

Learning and using the proper technical terms helps questions be unambiguous. If you're not sure what the right term is, ask *that* question.

---

Finally, a more subjective consideration: The way in which your question is written suggests that you are unfamiliar with how to construct a radio at all, and yet you are making specific unusual design choices up front. This can cause people to think that answering the specific question as asked is not actually worthwhile.

Comment: I made changes to the question.

Comment: @BenMadison Thank you, that has cleared it up.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are all unpaid volunteers here and our time is limited, it is expected that users will do a reasonable amount of research before asking a question here. Please see [How do I ask a good question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)?